# "E119: Not enough arguments" error with -nargs=+

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

These are my commands and functions that get name and address for app or url to launch em withing vim. They store the value in .txt files. Problem is that both commands give me "E119: Not enough arguments for function: Adda/Addw"

```
command! -nargs=+ Addw call Addw(<q-args>)
command! -nargs=+ Adda call Adda(<q-args>)

function! Addw(name, address)
 let web_addresses_file = expand('~/vimfiles/plugged/flexibleVP/data/webaddress.txt')
  let web_addresses = readfile(web_addresses_file)
  let new_line = a:name . ': ' . a:address

  call writefile(web_addresses + [new_line], web_addresses_file)
  echo 'Web address added: ' . new_line
endfunction

function! Adda(name, address)
let app_addresses_file = expand('~/vimfiles/plugged/flexibleVP/data/appaddress.txt')
  let app_addresses = readfile(app_addresses_file)
  let new_line = a:name . ': ' . a:address

  call writefile(app_addresses + [new_line], app_addresses_file)
  echo 'App address added: ' . new_line
endfunction
```

Tried with l:name and l:address;
Tried -nargs=*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just used f-args instead of q-args

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? How does this solve your problem? Where to read about `f-args`, `q-args`, etc.?

Comment: I think its because q-args is one whole string when you pass the parameters, while f-args splits it so the function can work with the different variables. use :help f-args or :help q-args

Comment: In your answer.